# QT database module error

Tags: c++, database, qt, postgresql-9.4

I am writing code in QT 5.6.0 version first time for database module  but I am getting error in this below line and i don't know how to solve that

code line:

```
QString insertTable=QString("INSERT INTO %1(%2,%3)" "VALUES (%4,%5)".arg(tableName).arg("\'schema\'","\'timestamp\'").arg(schema,timestamp));
```

error is:

```
C:\Users\ankit.ahlawat\Desktop\Infosys\git\IoTGateway_Database\database.cpp:212: error: request for member 'arg' in '"INSERT INTO %1(%2,%3)VALUES (%4,%5)"', which is of non-class type 'const char [36]'
                             "VALUES (%4,%5)".arg(tableName).arg("\'schema\'","\'timestamp\'").arg(schema,timestamp));

                                      ^
```

Comment: It's very hard to see what's going on with no formatting. I'm not even sure there's code there.

Comment: i am sorry for that,now i edited that Question

Answer (score 0):

You missplaced bracket while calling `QString` constructor:

```
QString("INSERT INTO %1(%2,%3)" "VALUES (%4,%5)".arg(tableName).arg("\'schema\'","\'timestamp\'").arg(schema,timestamp))
```

should be:

```
QString("INSERT INTO %1(%2,%3)" "VALUES (%4,%5)").arg(tableName).arg("\'schema\'","\'timestamp\'").arg(schema,timestamp)
```

Comment: @ankitAhlawat you should not directly form the queries since you are prone to an SQL Injection attack, what you should do is use [addBindValue()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#addBindValue)

Comment: @eyllanesc using addBindValue() i did it but now i was trying to do with QString so ...and i am new in QT

Comment: @ankitAhlawat but if you do that your application is vulnerable, **that's bad practice**